# How far can you manipulate someone with a Death Note?

Tags: death-note

We know that if you kill a person via a disease, the Death Note isn't limited to the 23 day rule. Now those who have watched death note know, you can manipulate a person to an extent. So my question is, could I write something like this?

> John Doe, Diabetes. Obeys every command from the person he knows as *J*, till he dies.

Could this work?

Answer (score 6):

There are different ways to interpret this question.
So let's break this down

> John Doe, Diabetes. Obeys every command from the person he knows as
>   ''J'', till he dies.

SO according to rule 23

> If you write die of disease like before with a specific disease's
>   name, but without a specific time, if it takes more than 24 days for
>   the human to die the 23 day rule will not take effect and the human
>   will die at an adequate time depending on the disease.

So the first part of your question

> John Doe, Diabetes.

works fine and the disease would take a natural course of action.

But here is the catch. You cannot let another person control the user as easily as you think. In the second sentence

> Obeys every command from the person he knows as ''J'', till he dies.

You have entered the name 'J' and would kill the person named as 'J' using a heart attack.

Also the line states "Every command" that 'J' gives. SO "every" command could also include that 'J' orders john doe to do things he would not like to do or 'J' could order 'Jon doe' to kill others which is not possible. According to TV tropes

> The first is that the Death Note can only kill one person per name. If
>   it brings harm to anyone else, the person will just die of a heart
>   attack. Also, aliases don't work, period. The Death Note doesn't know
>   who L or Kira or Wedy or Aiber or Near or Mello or anyone else with an
>   alias are. Real names only. However, you could write something like
>   "Report Siht. Demolishes a hotel, then subsequently dies." and then
>   write "L Lawliet. Crushed by falling debris as his hotel is
>   demolished." As long as two names are written, they are able to
>   interact.

So there is a limit of how much you can control and you cannot pass the control to someone else without killing them(since you wrote 'J' in death note already). So you statement in the death note would fail and would kill 'J' with a heart attack and also kill 'John doe' with a heart attack as the "Obeys 'every' command" is ambiguous.

**EDIT: In respect to the comment by Dark Yagami.**

**What works:**

> John Doe, diabetes. Eats fries and gummy bears, cheats on his
>   girlfriend

would work and you can control them as long as you want (at least till they die of diabetes).

**What does not work:**

> John Doe, diabetes. J, diabetes. John Doe obeys every command of *J*

won't work. Because you transfer control of power to change the lives of other people (in this case *J* could ask John Doe to kill someone or make John Doe do something impossible like fly to California from Japan in 2 mins. You cannot give an ambiguous command or control of other people's lives in the Death Note as the death note would just kill John Doe with a heart attack and *J* with diabetes in the above case.

One thing you guys must understand is, Death Note does not transfer the ability to control the lives of anyone other than the ones in Death Note. So you cannot make someone do something they would never contemplate. So handing over life of someone to another person is impossible for death note to do.

Source: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Headscratchers/DeathNoteRulesOfTheDeathNote

http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note

Comment: Okay. Now if I would write; John Doe, Diabetes. Obeys every command from the person he knows as: Josh Fortez, who also dies on diabetes. Would that work?

Comment: As I said in my second point of failure. Obey every commmand is ambiguous. The command could be something that would ask john doe to kill or affect others lives. It should be specific and not giving a power of control to anyone. No one can control other person's lives completely. You can write , john doe cheats with his girlfriend,eats fries and gummy bears. But not say "XYZ" can control "john doe". It would violate the rule that "XYZ" can alter lifespan of others and kill john doe with a heart attack and let "XYZ" die of diabetes.

Comment: check the answer for the edit with new example.Hope that makes it clear.

Comment: Then what about; John Doe, diabetes, will never say, nor confess to anyone, that the person he knows as Josh Fortzes, who dies with diabetes, is Kira. ?

Comment: Yes, that should work thoeretically .Also if John doe is someone who has a high sense of justice like lawliet or some of the police force who wants to catch kira, this would not work as it would command them to go against their sense of justice as it is something they would not do naturally. (Btw are u some english teacher?,where do you find all these convoluted sentences to break the death note.rofl) Yeah the death note is not intentionally made to control people like Geass and with the rules, the author has made so many fool proof mechanisms to stop it being used a human control device.

Comment: No I'm not an english teacher. Why do you think that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23929/discussion-between-darkyagami-and-imprfectluck).

Comment: I was just kidding ! lol

Comment: Ok then. One last question before I'll sleep... Do I write weird sentences?

Comment: Haha . No they are proper sentences and valid questions as far as i can understand .

Comment: "J" will not die of heart attack. You have to write the complete name, aliases won't work. Soon after getting the Death Note, Light wrote that a prisoner would write "L doesn't trust the police" (or something like that), but that didn't kill L.

Comment: 'J' is not an alias. we are talking as if J is a real name. just a filler like john Doe.

Answer (score 3):

I have watched the series only once and I am sure it is clearly stated in the series that it is absolutely possible to control a person's actions and manipulate him to do anything at all as long as it is physically possible for that person to do so.

But I don't really think if that command is going t work. You see, death note only kills a person and you can make a person do some stuff before he eventually dies. There might be a time limit for manipulating the person before he dies but I am not sure about that. I think I read something about this kind of stuff in the rules that appear in the series.

Comment: But the person does die in this situation. It's possible to control them, and even more possible to kill them through a disease, and since there's no rule that forbids that, I think that this could work.

Answer (score 2):

But there's another thing. For instance, he wrote Diabetes. The death note only makes the person do things that are physically possible. Otherwise, he dies of a heart attack.

Now what if the person is fit and doesn't consume a lot of sugar? Death note is only supposed to alter a person's state of mind and make him to stuff. But bringing about a biological change in a person sounds kind of impractical to me, save for the heart attack though. That's the default case scenario.

Comment: As long as you don't command them something which is impossible, I doubt, that they die from a heart attack.

Comment: Please edit your answer if it is a continuation from the other post.

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr:** This will not work and John will die of diabetes at an adequate time. In the off chance that John is so healthy that it would not make sense for him to die of diabetes, he will ironically die of a heart attack instead.

[image: !]

---

Before I start quoting the rules, let us go back to the beginning. **In chapter 6**, when Light just got his Death Note, he was as curious as you are right now and did similar experiments to the question you have been having. In one of the failed experiments he requested a prisoner to write down the words `I know L distrusts the police.` Light almost thought it would work, but he guessed that **it would be impossible for him to make people have thoughts they would never have**. In other words, even with the Death Note, Light could not do the impossible, whether it would be physically impossible (eg: travel to Paris in 30 minutes) or mentally impossible (eg: draw a picture of an unknown person or write down something you would not naturally think of).

So coming back to your question, where John has to obey every order *J* gives him. It would be impossible for John to be thinking about obeying **every** command *J* tells him. Therefore, similar to what happened to the prisoner, the situation of death would become void and only the cause of death would occur as written down.

> **Relevant rule:** Also, after writing the cause of death, even if the situation of death is written within 6 minutes and 40 seconds in the human world, the situation will only occur **to the victims whom it is possible**. For those where the situation is not possible, only the cause of death will occur. [HTU:LVI](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note#How_to_Use:_LVI)

This would make the situation of John's death impossible, but not the cause. Therefore John will still die of diabetes, with nothing more specified about his death. Unless he is medically unlikely of gaining diabetes, as mentioned earlier. In that case, he will die of a heart attack.

> **Relevant rule:** In the occasion where the cause of death is possible but the situation is not, **only the cause of death will take effect** for that victim. If both the cause and the situation are impossible, that victim will die of heart attack. [HTU:LV](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note#How_to_Use:_LV)

Since you did not specify a time of death, the [23-day rule](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note#How_to_Use:_XXVII) was bypassed and John will die at an adequate time needed for the disease to take effect.

> **Relevant rule:** If you write die of disease like before with a specific disease's name, but without a specific time, if it takes more than 24 days for the human to die the 23 day rule will not take effect and **the human will die at an adequate time** depending on the disease. [HTU:XXVIII](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note#How_to_Use:_XXVIII)

Comment: Then what about; John Doe, diabetes, will never say, nor confess to anyone, that the person he knows as Josh Fortzes, who dies with diabetes, is Kira. ?

Comment: @DarkYagami I'm not sure what you are asking. Are you asking whether John will keep quiet, or are you asking whether Josh will die as well, because his name is written in the DN too?

Comment: @DarkYagami I added the scene from the manga if that clears things up for you. Basically something will work if it strokes with the natural thought-process of the victim. If it contradicts this, it will just be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You can write that but the person would die in 10 seconds because you didn´t put the time when he dies. (I think it was 10 seconds)