# If a Death Note user specifies, along with the actual target, the name of a person whose face the user doesn't know, will that person live?

Tags: death-note

It has been confirmed by L that if a person's name is written in the Death Note, and they are written to die in a form that specifies another person's name, (like "L Lawliet will die after he deletes all his evidence on Light Yagi and goes to Misa Amani's apartment") then all of them would die of a heart attack.

This is due to [Rule XI](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note#How_to_Use:_XI)

> 3. [...] once the victim's name has been written, the individual's death can never be avoided.

The rule above may appear to trump [Rule X](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note#How_to_Use:_X)

> 2. Whether the cause of the individual's death is either a suicide or accident, if the death leads to the death of more than the intended, the person will simply die of a heart attack. [...]

However, it does not. "The victim" is automatically anyone whose name is written in the Death Note.

Suppose somebody uses a Death Note to kill someone and specifies another person's name in the description. **Will that person — who is specified, but not intended to be killed — live, if the Death Note user does not know their face?**

Comment: Possibly covered by the answers in [this](http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/21687/2604)? The idea is that as long as the name appears, the usual rules for killing people are applied, and so the face must be known.

Answer (score 2):

The person would live in many cases. That rule indeed says that if multiple people are specified, that they all would end up having a heart attack, but **it does not circumvent all the other existing rules**. You would still need to have the person's face in mind while writing and the name should be the person's real name and not a nickname. The only thing that rule says is that all other details regarding the first person's death are just ignored.

For example if you write

> Person A stabbed to the heart. Person A would hug person B and would then kill person C. Person D would become jealous and would stab person A.

the Death Note would read it as

> Person A <strike>stabbed to the heart.</strike> Person A <strike>would hug</strike> Person B <strike>and would then kiss</strike> Person C. Person D <strike>would become jealous and would stab</strike> Person A.

or

> Person A
>   Person B
>   Person C
>   Person D

So unless you had the specific person's face in mind while writing the name or unless the name was fake, the person would die from a heart attack.

Answer (score 2):

According to [How to Use: I](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note#How_to_Use:_I)

> This note will not take effect unless the writer has the person's face in their mind when writing his/her name. Therefore, people sharing the same name will not be affected.

Therefore, answer for this question is
**That people, who Deathnote user does not know their face, will live.**