# Can you manipulate a person using an alias with the death note?

Tags: death-note

So. Let's say John has a death note. Now there's a killer on the run, and John doesn't know his name and face. Now he writes the name of a criminal in his death note, to indirectly catch the killer. He writes:

Bob Zorto gets stabbed to death, at 12:30, by the serial killer, who uses the alias ''Shadow Killer''.

Could that actually work?

Comment: Also [related](http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/21687/6166), [related](http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/21659/6166) and [related](http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/22222/6166).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, this would not work.**

[In chapter 45 page 17](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZi7C.png), we see how L tells us that nicknames would not work and the cause of death would turn into an heart attack. The exact quote for reference was:

> It is not possible to have "Make Amane Misa talk about L and then kill her", and it would turn into a heart attack since "L" is a nickname.

[image]