# Could one make a specific person shoot someone dead using the deathnote?

Tags: death-note

Rule X.2 saies "Whether the cause of the individual's death is either a suicide or accident, if the death leads to the death of more than the intended, the person will simply die of a heart attack. This is to ensure that other lives are not influenced."

This is generally (including in canon) interpreted as "One can't make a specific person kill". We all agree that based on this rule one can write "Mr. A get shot" but not "B has a heart attack after shooting someone". My question is if it would be possible to write "A get shot. B has a heart attack after shooting A". The name "Mr.A" is in the notebook so it should work but I am pretty sure that Light or Ryuk called it impossible.

Out of canon I understand that Kira is an OP puppet master even without the ability of blaiming specific persons for a homocide he commited (just think about what would have happened if one member of the task force shoot another one and get shot on his own so that light now has a gun and human shilds to kill L withuout deathnote or eye witnesses) but in canon there should be no reason why it should not work.

Comment: This seems to be covered in part here, at least in answers: https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/21659/2604

Comment: The answers almost match but they miss the specific person aspect. "A heart attak 9:30 after raging in a hotel" "B bloode loss after beeing beaten up in a hotel 9:10" still can make A rage in one hotel and B die in another one. I want to know if one can specificly link two persons with known names and faces if one write both name in the book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you wrote both Mr.A and Mr.B's name in the notebook
and their deaths (which is caused by the book) correlate with each other, this would be possible. writing their times of death would increase the chances of this working.

for example you know both Mr.A, and Mr.B meet everyday at 7:00
you could just make it so that Mr.B gets "influenced" at 6:30 and Mr.A gets shot at 7:00, making sure you write Mr.A's fate first on the death note.